# Android - Spinner is not stable in custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, custom-adapter

I have a custom array adapter with 2 textView, 1 spinner and 1 checkbox. **When I run my app and select the item in the spinner and scroll the custom adapter the strings in spinner is not stable. It's changing its position in the customAdapter.** The code for my getView(),

```
public class ListAdap extends ArrayAdapter<List> {

    private static final String TAG = "ListAdap";

    private final ArrayList<List> nameList;


    public ListAdap(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<List> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);
        this.nameList = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ArrayList excuseList;
        TextView number;
        Spinner excuse;
        TextView name;
        CheckBox isPaid;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        final List currentNameList = getItem(position);

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.pending_list, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            final ArrayList excuseList = new ArrayList();
            excuseList.add("");
            excuseList.add("Tommorow");
            excuseList.add("Sunday");
            excuseList.add("Monday");
            excuseList.add("Tuesday");
            excuseList.add("Wednesday");
            excuseList.add("Thursday");
            excuseList.add("Friday");
            excuseList.add("Next Week");

            viewHolder.excuse = (Spinner) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.excuseSpinner);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, excuseList);
            viewHolder.excuse.setAdapter(adapter);

            final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;

            viewHolder.excuse.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                    currentNameList.get(position).setPos(String.valueOf(pos));

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.excuse.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(currentNameList.get(position).getPos()));



            viewHolder.number = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            viewHolder.number.setText(currentNameList.getNumber());

            viewHolder.name = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.name.setText(currentNameList.getName());

            viewHolder.isPaid = (CheckBox) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            listItemView.setTag(viewHolder);

            final ViewHolder finalViewHolder1 = viewHolder;
            viewHolder.isPaid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    List namelist = (List) cb.getTag();

                    if (String.valueOf(cb.isChecked()) == "true"){
                        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(cb.isChecked()) + finalViewHolder1.name.getText());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),finalViewHolder1.name.getText() +" Paid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                    }

                    namelist.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) listItemView.getTag();
        }

        List list = nameList.get(position);


        viewHolder.number.setText(currentNameList.number);
        viewHolder.name.setText(currentNameList.name);
        viewHolder.isPaid.setChecked(list.ispaid());

        viewHolder.isPaid.setTag(list);
        viewHolder.excuse.setTag(list);


        return listItemView;


    }

    public class MultiSelectSpinner {

        private String pos;

        public String getPos()
        {
            return pos;
        }

        public void setPos(String pos)
        {
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }



}
```

List.class

```
public class List{

    String number;
    String name;
    Boolean paid = false;



    public List(String number, String name, boolean paid) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.paid = paid;

    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Boolean ispaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected)
    {
        this.paid = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Did you get the answer yet? I have the same problem now.

Comment: dude... use RecyclerView instead of listView